# TypeScript Debugging in Chrome between CommonJS and AMD

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript

I have been digging around trying to find the answer to this:

[How can I debug modular TypeScript with source maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500322/how-can-i-debug-modular-typescript-with-source-maps)

[TypeScript generating wrong JS in Release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245182/typescript-generating-wrong-js-in-release-mode)

[Typescript AMD Modules in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762462/typescript-amd-modules-in-visual-studio)

but so far no luck. I have a Visual Studio 2015 Angular project with TypeScript. I am trying to get debugging working. My TypeScript files are coded with CommonJS. When I run the app and try and debug it errors saying "exports is not defined." When I change the app to use AMD it runs in IE but not in chrome as the js gets created like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
function sayHello() {
    alert("I am here");
}
exports.sayHello = sayHello;
function yo() {
    alert("yo");
}
exports.yo = yo;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=TestMessage.js.map
```

and Chrome now says "define" is not defined. If I leave the mode as CommonJS both Chrome and IE error saying "exports is not defined." Seems like I am missing something here. Any ideas what? Here is why TS file:

```
export function sayHello() {
alert("I am here");
}

export function yo() {
alert("yo");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonjs is a module system used mainly by nodejs.
AMD is intended for the browser.

You can use what ever you like, but each requires a library to make it work in the browser.

For commonjs you can use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

For AMD you can use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

Comment: So we are using webpack but here is the issue I am trying to over come. Webpack takes all my TS and puts it into one file. To easy Dev debugging I am trying to keep them all in different files. However, I can't seem to get webpack (awesome-typescript-loader) to keep all the files separate. This probably goes in the face of webpack.

Comment: We are actually using [webpack-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stream). And to do what I was after I found [vinyl-named](https://github.com/shama/vinyl-named) that lets me stream out all the individual files. So I think I have this now.